# List all available ingress controllers on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I have a GKE cluster with Traefik being used as an ingress controller.

I want to create a [GKE ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer), but I can't find anywhere which `kubernetes.io/ingress.class` to use.

I tried to use `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: gce`, but nothing happened... it's almost like the ingress was completely ignored.

Is there a way to list all available ingress controllers/classes? Or, at least, which `kubernetes.io/ingress.class` should I use to create a GKE Ingress? (I'll still use traefik for other ingresses).

Comment: You can find all available GKE ingress controllers here https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/#using-multiple-ingress-controllers. BTW, on GKE, Ingress-GCE runs by default but it is managed for you by GKE https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/blob/master/docs/deploy/gke/README.md and you don't need to specify class for it. Please provide more information what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run describe on the Ingress. If you see create/add events, you have an Ingress controller running in the cluster, otherwise, you probably have the HttpLoadBalancing(GKE Ingress Controller) add-on disabled on your GKE cluster.

Answer (score 1):

On GKE, The **kubernetes.io/ingress.class: gce** is the default ingress class, if there is no an annotation defined under the metadata section, the Ingress Resource uses the GCP GCLB L7 load balancer to serve traffic. So have you tried setting the annotation to an empty string?

Being said that, answering the following questions it will help me to understand the contest:

1. Could you please define you use case? Are you trying to define two
   ingress for the same service or convert to curren Traefik to a GCE
   ingress?
2. Could you please attach your GKE ingress definition to see
   if there is a sintaxis error ?